# replace a range of number in a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I would like to replace a range of number in a file with another range. Let say I have:

```
/dev/raw/raw16
/dev/raw/raw17
/dev/raw/raw18
```

And I want modify them as:

```
/dev/raw/raw1
/dev/raw/raw2
/dev/raw/raw3
```

I know I can do it using sed or awk but just cannot write it correctly. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'/dev/raw/raw' '{print FS (++c)}' ile

/dev/raw/raw1
/dev/raw/raw2
/dev/raw/raw3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recomment changing device names.
Anyway, just to replace letters or numbers you could use the option 's' with sed.

```
cat file.txt | sed s/raw16/raw1/g; > newfile.txt
```

In this example you replace all the raw16 with raw1.
Here some other examples ...

```
 sed 's/foo/bar/'                    # replaces in each row the first foo only
 sed 's/foo/bar/4'                   # replaces in each row every 4.
 sed 's/foo/bar/g'                   # replaces all foo with bar
 sed 's/\(.*\)foo/\1bar/'            # replace the last only per line
```

.

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I'm actually looking for a regex to change a range of number let say raw[16-18] with raw[1-3]

Answer (score 0):

```
# using /raw as field separator, so $2 is the end number in this case
awk -v From=16 -v To=18 -v NewStart=1 -F '/raw' '
  # for lines where last number is in the scope
  $2 >= From && $2 <=To {
     # change last number to corresponding in new scope
     sub( /[0-9]+$/, $2 - From + NewStart)
     }
  # print (default action of a non 0 value "filter") the line (modified or not)
  7
  ' file.txt \
 > newfile.txt
```

Note:

- adapt the field separator for your real need
- suite for your sample of data, not if other element are in the line but you could easily adapt this code foir your purpose